# Too high pulse while running

Tags: training, running, bicycling

I'm 36 so my max pulse is about 184. I'm a bit overweight, 98 kg. My problem is that I can't hold my pulse down. My usual pulse is about 148-154 (~80%). I'm not able to run slower. I would like to run with lower pulse, like about 130(~70%).

If I go uphill, my pulse rises fast.

I have no training plan, I just run for fun. I can run about 14km.

Fartlek or interval runs can solve my problem? Or what if I bike a lot in this lower pulse range?

Comment: I feel like we're missing a bit of information, so here goes: How did you calculate your max heartrate? Have you done sports before, if so then what and how recently? Are you on a diet, if so then how big is your deficit? Do you have a demanding/stressful job? Do you get enough sleep (how many hours, on average)?

Comment: If you have not had a maximal stress test of some sort, you have no idea what your max heart rate is. 220-age is a very bad myth based on bad data.

Comment: 220-age is wrong, it was based on bad data, and should never have even been written.

Comment: I used simple formula for max heartrate: 220-age. I've checked my Polar running watch, it says my max heartrate is 184 (it has test to calculate it). As a teenager I've done couple of sports: basketball, hiking, cycling. Five years ago I started running, after half year of training I completed a half marathon. That time I was about 90kg. During that training I had the same problem, I wasn't able to run with 130 heartrate. I'm not on diet. My job isn't stressful. I sleep enough, 7-8 hours.

Comment: The Polar watch uses 220-age as an estimate as well. 220 - age is meaningless. Don't use it. Not sure how else to say it.

Answer (score 0):

First I would not use a generic formula to determine your max heart rate. Ideally you could do a Vo2Max test and get that but your next best way is to run a couple of races to determine where you max HR is. Since you are already seeing a spike as you go up a hill you can use that to figure out a reasonable Max HR.

Find a hill that is about 300 meters long. Sprint up the hill and slow jog back down for recovery. Do this at least 6 times. You will be able to find your Max heart rate or get fairly close to it.

The question or statement

> I'm not able to run slower

If you are jogging to the point of walking then try walk jogging. How fast are you running when you can't run slower?

Here are a couple of options for your 14k runs. (And by the way you don't always have to run 14k)

4k warmup, 2k at 1/2 marathon pace, 2k at 10k pace, 2k at 5k pace, 4k cool down.

Make sure you are not doing this everyday. You should mix this up with recovery runs then hard work outs. No more than 2 hard workouts per week and I would incorporate one long slow run on the weekend.

In addition to the above you should incorporate Hill repeats and Speed training.

It will take some time, maybe more than year depending on your weekly kilometers.

Comment: I usually run with about 10 km/h. I usually train twice or three times a week. 14km is my long rung usually on weekends.